# Refreshing content in an update panel after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, vb.net, updatepanel

I have a simple command event that toggles the visibility of two buttons.

When the controls are wrapped in an update panel as below, each subsequent click does not toggle the visibility of the buttons even though the code executes as expected.

**Testing**

- The code works as expected when the update panel is removed.
- After clicking the button refreshing the page reflects the changes made.
- The issue clearly lies with refreshing the content after a postback.
- I have tried `upd.update` and `updateMode="always"`

**ASPX**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upd" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="Server">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnOn" runat="Server" Text="ON" CommandName="ON" CommandArgument='<%#: Container.ItemIndex%>' UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnOff" runat="Server" Text="OFF" CommandName="OFF" CommandArgument='<%#: Container.ItemIndex%>' UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**VB.NET**

```
Protected Sub Page_PreRenderComplete(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRenderComplete
  For Each item In rpt.Items
    'Do a check and set output'
    btnOn.Visible = Not Output
    btnOff.Visible = Output
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? I have run into a similar situation and have not been able to identify what causes my updatePanel not to update when other updatepanels I've used in the same application work fine.

Comment: @jroyce I believe I did resolve it but can't remember how, sorrry. If you have a specific example for your issue though I might be able to help. My knowledge of update panels is much better than it was two years ago.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53438582/data-going-out-of-synch-when-using-gridview-inside-updatepanel is the detailed situation I am running into.