# Data Going Out of Synch when using GridView inside UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, gridview, updatepanel

Data in my GridView inside an UpdatePanel is going out of synch with the database and I can't figure out why. This has resulted in incorrect updates to the database which I have to fix rapidly! Can anyone help?

I have multiple UpdatePanels that have GridViews inside that can be edited by the user. There is a search feature and filter buttons that select queried data from the database and display in the GridView. There is sorting enabled and the "out of synchness" occurs mostly when sorting and then editing a field.

The data comes from a SQL Database. I can update the data directly through OnTextChange option of my TemplateField like this:

```
<asp:GridView 
    ID="GridView4" 
    runat="server" 
    OnSorting="TaskGridView_Sorting" 
    AllowSorting="True" 
    Width="100%" >
    <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="name" HeaderText="Name">
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" CssClass="col_name" />
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="name" AutoPostBack="True" CssClass="col_name" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name") %>' Width=180 OnTextChanged="text_change" />
    </ItemTemplate>                 
    </asp:TemplateField> 
    ...
```

I have my gridview inside an UpdatePanel that has these options:

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
         ...
```

I have enabled partial rendering like this:

```
    <ajaxToolKit:ToolkitScriptManager EnablePartialRendering="true" runat="server" />
```

I have buttons that filter the data by requerying the database and displaying just the filtered data like this:

```
DataGrid_Load(DAL.Search_reg_log(OrgText.Text, searchText, searchCol), "reg");
```

The gridview gets its data loaded like this:

```
private void DataGrid_Load(DataTable command, string type)
{   
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    dataTable = command;
    string sortDir = ViewState["SortDirection"] as string;
    string sortExp = ViewState["SortExpression"] as string;

    if(ViewState["SortExpression"] != null)
    {                   
        dataTable = resort(dataTable, sortExp, sortDir);
    }

    try 
    {
        var query = from c in dataTable.AsEnumerable() 
                   where c.Field<string>("status") == "Invoiced" && c.Field<string>("reg_cat_id") != "Archive"
                      || c.Field<string>("status") == "Confirmed" && c.Field<string>("reg_cat_id") != "Archive" 
                  select c ;    

        if(query.Any()){
            DataTable t2 = query.CopyToDataTable();
            GridView4.DataSource = t2;
            GridView4.DataBind();
        } else {
            GridView4.DataSource = new DataTable();
            GridView4.DataBind();
        }
    }           
    catch(Exception e) {
        ErrorText.Text = "Caught Exception: " + e;              
    }

...
```

I have isolated one cause of the data errors which occurs after sorting a column and then

```
protected void TaskGridView_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{               
    string sortExp = ViewState["SortExpression"] as string;     
    string sortDir = ViewState["SortDirection"] as string;
    if(sortDir == "asc" & sortExp == e.SortExpression.ToString())
        ViewState["SortDirection"] = "desc";
    else
        ViewState["SortDirection"] = "asc";
    ViewState["SortExpression"] = e.SortExpression.ToString();

    if(searchCol != "" && searchText != "")
        DataGrid_Load(DAL.Search_reg_log(OrgText.Text, searchText, searchCol), "reg");
    else
        DataGrid_Load(DAL.reg_log(HeadText.Text, OrgText.Text), "reg");     

    UpdatePanels();

}
```

Here is the resort function:

```
public static DataTable resort(DataTable dt, string colName, string direction)
{
    dt.DefaultView.Sort = colName + " " + direction;
    dt = dt.DefaultView.ToTable();
    return dt;
}
```

Please help with some direction of what might be causing this.

Comment: Anyone interested in the bounty?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are having some trouble with GridView and updating them. I will post a complete working example below. Start with that and gradually update that code to fit your own needs, like getting data with `var query = from c in dataTable.AsEnumerable()`. The important thing is to sort the data every time you (re)bind the GridView data. And I'm not sure what is happening inside `resort`, but you have to use `dt.DefaultView.ToTable();` to save the sorting in the DataTable.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
            DataKeyNames="ID" AllowSorting="true" 
            OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting"
            AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
            AutoGenerateEditButton="true"
            OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing"
            OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit"
            OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating">
            <Columns>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Eval("ID") %>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="name">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Eval("name") %>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text=' <%# Eval("name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

        <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //bind data in an ispostback check
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DataGrid_Load();
    }
}


private void DataGrid_Load()
{
    //load the datatable data
    DataTable dt = source;

    //check if the viewsstate existst
    if (ViewState["SortExpression"] != null && ViewState["SortDirection"] != null)
    {
        //sort the datatable before binding it to the gridview
        dt.DefaultView.Sort = ViewState["SortExpression"] + " " + ViewState["SortDirection"];
        dt.DefaultView.ToTable();
    }

    //bind the sorted datatable to the gridvidw
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}


protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    //load the previous sorting settigns
    string sortExp = ViewState["SortExpression"] as string;
    string sortDir = ViewState["SortDirection"] as string;

    //reverse the direction if the column is the same as the previous sort
    if (sortDir == "asc" & sortExp == e.SortExpression.ToString())
        ViewState["SortDirection"] = "desc";
    else
        ViewState["SortDirection"] = "asc";

    //put the current sort column in the viewstate
    ViewState["SortExpression"] = e.SortExpression.ToString();

    //rebind data
    DataGrid_Load();
}


protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    //set the edit index and rebind data
    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    DataGrid_Load();
}


protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
    //reset the edit index and rebind data
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    DataGrid_Load();
}


protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    //use findcontrol to locate the textbox in the edit template
    TextBox tb = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextBox1");

    //get the id of the row from the datakeys
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0]);

    //show result for testing
    Literal1.Text = "ID: " + id + "<br>Name: " + tb.Text;

    //reset the edit index and rebind data
    GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(null, null);
}
```

Comment: Thank for this detailed answer. If I have several gridviews is it correct that I load all of them from within my DataGrid_Load function? Or should they each have a separate load function?

Comment: It is better to load them separately, it saves some overhead. And depending on how you are fetching data, it could save some database queries.

Comment: Ok so best would be separate dataGrid1_Load, dataGrid2_Load l, etc.

Comment: Yes, then you can call that method from somewhere else also if needed.

Comment: I am not using the RowEditing event at all. My text fields of the grid view each use the onTextChanged option where the database is updated. Is this wrong to not use rowEditing event? Could this be related to the issue I am having?

Comment: If you're not re-binding the updated data to the grid view in your `OnTextChanged="text_change"` event, that's likely the issue. Despite the change of value in the textbox, and in the database, the page will probably have retained the old values in the ViewState. This will be restored to the page, instead of the new value.

Comment: I believe that was the issue. Thank you!